# Question about a proof I was given

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I was given a proof for my geometry work today and, upon further investigation, I think I found a way to solve it pretty easily. Here is the "problem" (I still call them math problems): 
(Can't post images but there is a diagram of an isosceles triangle)

Given: $\triangle ABD$ is isosceles with long side BD.
$AC \perp BD$

Prove: $C$ is the Midpoint of $BD$.

Okay so this is the way I would like to solve this (not that it really matters because the teacher gave me a specific way he wanted me to solve it, but I want to know if I'm right):

---

Statement:
$\triangle ABD$ is an isosceles triangle

Reason: Given

---

Statement:
$AC \perp BD$

Reason:
Given

---

Statement:
C is the Midpoint of BD

Given:
Def. Of a bisector

---

Is this correct? I feel like it should be since the definition of a bisector is: 
A line, ray or segment which cuts another linesegment into two equal parts.

Thanks!

Comment: Um... Who said that $C$ bisects $BD$?  It *does*, but that's what you have to prove.  You can't use the definition of bisector if *nothing* was declared or shown to be a bisector.

Comment: "A line, ray or segment which cuts another linesegment into two equal parts."  Yes.... and how does that apply to the situation given?  Is there anything in your diagram that you were told cuts a line segment into equal parts?

Comment: @fleablood sorry, I meant to say "perpendicular bisector" not just "perpendicular". I will correct that.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe this was given as an exercise and that the intended answer is anything more complicated than that.  Yes, this works but it is so very obvious, I really doubt that this was the actual problem.  Given that $AC$ is perpendicular but not given that it is a bisector, or that it is a biscector but not given it is perpendicular and proving it is both, is a very standard excercise.  But proving that a bisector intersects at a midpoint is just a definition and very trivial.

Comment: @fleablood yeah, i know. He wanted us to prove that the two right triangles made by the bisector and then use like "Hypotenuse and leg" or "Leg and leg" etc. To solve it. It was still stupid though

Comment: You _can_ post images: just press `Ctr-G` or click the ‘mountain+sun’ icon in the toolbar.

Comment: @PJTraill thanks PJ, but i uploaded the photo to the post but i have to have like 10 reputation points before i can post images :/ i don't post often enough to get points